# How can refresh only a div which contains google chart and php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, charts, google-visualization

I have an admin page that contains several divs. And some divs contain google charts.
My charts are feeding from php+MySQL data.

Some divs(or chart) update 60 sec. Some divs(or chart) will be updated 1 hour.
So that different divs should update different period. (That's why I don't refresh whole page.

Anyway,When I refresh page there is no problem, but when I try to update my div, div updates, but there is nothing inside about graph.
Can you help me?

**Here is my php code:**

```
  // QUERY AND PHP ARRAY FOR JSON 
  $query = "SELECT CONCAT(cdate,' ',chour,':00:00') AS ctime ,sum(bytesin*0.000002222) as totalKbpsin, sum(bytesout*0.000002222) as totalKbpsout FROM traffic_user_daily group by cdate,chour HAVING ctime >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ";

 $result = $conn->query($query);
 $rows= array();
 $table = array();
 $table['cols'] = array(
 array('label' => 'Tarih' , 'type' => 'string'),
 array('label' => 'Inbound' , 'type' => 'number'),
 array('label' => 'Outbound' , 'type' => 'number'),

 );
 foreach($result as $r) {
 $temp = array();
 $temp[] = array('v' => (string) substr($r['ctime'],11,5));
 $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['totalKbpsin']);
 $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['totalKbpsout']);
 $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
 }
 $table['rows'] = $rows;
 $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
 ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        // CHART JAVA CODE
        google.charts.load('visualization','current', {'packages':['corechart','bar'], 'language': 'en'});

        // Draw the line chart is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBigChart);     


        // Callback that draws the line chart

        function drawBigChart() {            
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);

            var options = {

                chartArea: {
                    'height': '80%',
                    left: "5%" 
                },

                legend: {
                    position: 'right', 
                    textStyle: {
                        color: '#bdbdbd', 
                        fontSize: 12
                    }
                },

                hAxis: {
                    showTextEvery:2,
                    textStyle: {color: '#bdbdbd',
                    fontSize: 12,
                    },
                    baselineColor: '#bdbdbd',
                    gridlines: {color:'bdbdbd'},
                },


                vAxis: {
                    baselineColor: '#bdbdbd',
                    textStyle: {color:'#bdbdbd'},
                    gridlines: {color:'#bdbdbd' },
                    minValue: 0,
                },

                intervals: { 'style':'area' },
                curveType: 'function',
                crosshair: {orientation: 'vertical'},

                animation: {
                    startup: true,
                    duration: 1000
                },
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            chart.draw(data, options);

        }

</script>
   <!-- OUTER DIV -->
                <div class="col s12 m12">
                  <!-- CHART DIV -->
                    <div id="dash_big_chart" class="card">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div>
                                <span class="card-title grey-text lighten-1">
    <?php echo $_SESSION['companyname'] ?></span></div>
    <div id="chart_div">
    </div></div></div></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    /// refresh script ////

    setInterval(function(){
      $("#dash_big_chart").load('big_chart.php')
      },60000);
    });

    </script>
```

And then I have another php page named big_chart.php. That contains Query and array for JSON part , Graph java except  google.charts.load and CHAR DIV.

Can you hep me?

Comment: What exactly does "big_chart.php" return? If it is JSON data you want to use it with google charts. $("#dash_big_chart").load('big_chart.php') doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solve it:

```
google.charts.load('visualization','current', {'packages':['corechart','bar'], 'language': 'en'});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBigChart);
function drawBigChart() {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "get_new_data.php",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false
            }).responseText;

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
        var options = {something  for visualisation}
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
        }
```

AND

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#dash_kullanicisayisi").load('kullanicisayisi.php')
            $.ajax({
                'url': 'get_new_data.php', // url should return only JSON data
                'dataType': 'json',
                'async': true
            }).success(function(result) {
                //Draw the chart again with the updated data
                drawBigChart(result);
            });
        },60000);
    });
```

solves my problem. Now chart refresh and populate new datas.
Thank for your assistances.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery load() wants to load HTML into a page element.

What you want to do is totally different:
You want to get json data via an ajax request, and then let googlecharts redraw the chart with that new data.

Therfor you have to add the json data as parameter to your drawBigChart function.

Code would look like this:

```
// For the first load you can pass the json data just like you did before.
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
    drawBigChart(<?=$jsonTable?>);
});

function drawBigChart(json_data) {
    // pass the parameter into the google charts DataTable
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json_data);
    var options = {...}; // I left out the options here only to make the code more visible
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

// For the interval you retrieve the data via ajax request and pass
// it to the drawBigChart function
setInterval(function(){
    $.getJSON( "big_chart.php", function( data ) {
        drawBigChart(data);
    });
},60000);
```

Comment: When I do this, There is no chart. But I get viv in another div which have same like Matryoshka doll.

Answer (score 0):

In your `setInterval()` you are replacing `<div id="dash_big_chart"/>` and everything inside it, including the `<div id="chart_div"/>` which is the area where Google is drawing the chart.

However, the code that actually draws the chart is up above, in the JavaScript, is the function `drawBigChart()`.  And the data that gets drawn to the chart is

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
```

To accomplish what you want, you need to refactor.  **You don't need to download new HTML, you just need to download new data and update the chart.**

Change the `drawBigChart()` method to take an argument which is the chart data, so you would call it like `drawBigChart(jsonTable)`.

Once you can do that, instead of loading in HTML and replacing a div, as you are currently doing, you just need to load in new JSON data and call `drawBigChart(newJsonTable)` with the new data.

Something like

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    'url': 'get_new_data.php', // url should return only JSON data
    'dataType': 'json',
    'async': true
  }).success(function(result) {
    // Draw the chart again with the updated data
    drawBigChart(result);
  });
}, 60000); // 60 second refresh
```

Comment: sorry I was slightly faster :P still correct though

Comment: Sorry user2415266 but dont understand ?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my page as you describe:

```
google.charts.load('visualization','current', {'packages':  ['corechart','bar'], 'language': 'en'});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBigChart);
        function drawBigChart(jsonTable) { 
           var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);

            var options = { some visual thing};
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

And Interval script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#activeuserlist").on("click", "a.modal-trigger", function(){
 $('#modalkes').openModal();
});
setInterval(function(){
    $("#activeuserlist").load('activeuserlist2.php') //another DIV

    $("#dash_kullanicisayisi").load('kullanicisayisi.php') //ANother DIV

   $.ajax({
    'url': 'get_new_data.php', // url should return only JSON data
    'dataType': 'json',
    'async': true
    }).success(function(result) {
    // Draw the chart again with the updated data
   drawBigChart(result);
   });
   },60000);
 });
```

And my get_new_data.php is like that:

```
   <?php
   require_once("inc/functions.php"); 
   startSession();
   connectDB($conn);

   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul');
   mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

   $now = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
   $query = "SELECT CONCAT(cdate,' ',chour,':00:00') AS ctime ,sum(bytesin*0.000002222) as totalKbpsin, sum(bytesout*0.000002222) as totalKbpsout FROM traffic_user_daily group by cdate,chour HAVING ctime >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ";
   $result = $conn->query($query);

   $rows= array();
   $table = array();
   $table['cols'] = array(
   array('label' => 'Tarih' , 'type' => 'string'),
   array('label' => 'Inbound' , 'type' => 'number'),
   array('label' => 'Outbound' , 'type' => 'number'),

   );
   foreach($result as $r) {
   $temp = array();
   $temp[] = array('v' => (string) substr($r['ctime'],11,5));
   $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['totalKbpsin']);
   $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['totalKbpsout']);
   $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
   }
   $table['rows'] = $rows;
   $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
   echo $jsonTable;
   ?>
```

And when I browse this page I get something like JSON Data:

```
    {"cols":[{"label":"Tarih","type":"string"},{"label":"Inbound","type":"number"},{"label":"Outbound","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"14:00"},{"v":6213},{"v":891}]},{"c":[{"v":"15:00"},{"v":6914},{"v":915}]},{"c":[{"v":"16:00"},{"v":5645},{"v":1789}]},{"c":[{"v":"17:00"},{"v":5821},{"v":1771}]},{"c":[{"v":"18:00"},{"v":3242},{"v":1753}]},{"c":[{"v":"19:00"},{"v":7536},{"v":685}]},{"c":[{"v":"20:00"},{"v":6902},{"v":696}]},{"c":[{"v":"21:00"},{"v":7140},{"v":1184}]},{"c":[{"v":"22:00"},{"v":5971},{"v":502}]},{"c":[{"v":"23:00"},{"v":9506},{"v":1353}]},{"c":[{"v":"00:00"},{"v":8783},{"v":2855}]},{"c":[{"v":"01:00"},{"v":3125},{"v":1044}]},{"c":[{"v":"02:00"},{"v":2500},{"v":1858}]},{"c":[{"v":"03:00"},{"v":534},{"v":1721}]},{"c":[{"v":"04:00"},{"v":658},{"v":1940}]},{"c":[{"v":"05:00"},{"v":839},{"v":93}]},{"c":[{"v":"06:00"},{"v":1041},{"v":200}]},{"c":[{"v":"07:00"},{"v":1154},{"v":97}]},{"c":[{"v":"08:00"},{"v":2684},{"v":1467}]},{"c":[{"v":"09:00"},{"v":7297},{"v":2099}]},{"c":[{"v":"10:00"},{"v":4143},{"v":1244}]},{"c":[{"v":"11:00"},{"v":7645},{"v":1535}]},{"c":[{"v":"12:00"},{"v":4411},{"v":868}]},{"c":[{"v":"13:00"},{"v":5323},{"v":1119}]}]}
```

Graph is refreshed as image but not shows new values.
I check from HTTPFOX that  get_new_data.php pull correct datas, Chart refreshes. But chart not change.  Still same graph.

Comment: If , `var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>); `          change as  `var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonTable)`  at initialize graph is empty but then updated sucessfully. It means, at first data is php then java. And script waits data as json. right?

Comment: Then something is wrong with the first data input. Try `drawBigChart(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);` instead of `drawBigChart(<?=$jsonTable?>);`